Не работает загрузка файлов в Яндекс Диск (REST API) через php SDK
Я использую это SDK: https://github.com/jack-theripper/yandex?tab=readme-ov-file
Сделал сервис для работы с Яндекс диском. Его задача - загружать файлы с диска и отправлять их туда. Протестировал работу на методе получения ссылки на скачивание файла по названию - работает отлично. Т.е до этапа с поиском нужной папки работает все красиво.
Проблема такая:
Когда я пытаюсь загрузить файл в диск через upload(), каждый раз вылетает ошибка: По указанному пути "app:/" уже существует папка с таким именем.
Я попробовал внутри папки приложения создать новую пустую папку и пытался загружать в нее файлы - ошибка та же, отличается только путь к папке на диске. Хотя, опять же, папка пустая.
Роут файла: ...files/1713353535661fb33f3b9d00.80370243.pdf
Сам файл на сервере есть, открывается, с ним все ок.
Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как решили? Или, возможно, у кого-то есть идеи куда еще копать, чтобы пофиксить?

Разобрался.
Смысол в том, что я пытался создать папку, и предполагал, что дальше, через метод upload() я в нее загружу новый файл.
А оказалось, что для загрузки файлов нужно сначала было создать папку (test_folder), а дальше создавать для каждого файла свой ресурс по роуту 'app:/test_folder/ВАШЕ_НАЗВАНИЕ_ФАЙЛА_ТУТ' – и от этого пустого ресурса вызывать upload()
